# Middle align difference: Material-icons vs Font-Awesome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, google-material-icons

Why Material-icons cannot set vertical align middle with text even though exactly same css of Font-Awesome? (with Bootstrap3)

Both of them has `&:before { content: '{icontext}' }`

[image: image: Left: Material-icons / Right: Font-Awesome]

```
<a class="btn btn-default">  
  <i class="material-icons"></i>  
  <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
  123
</a>
```

---

```
.material-icons {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 'Material Icons';
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

---

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

edit:

attached jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/laires/guxwxvzL/

Comment: i don't know the exact answer to your question but if the issue is align vertically it is done easily by flexbox

Comment: Post a working code snippet, with the linked library versions you used

Comment: ok, i attached jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/laires/guxwxvzL/

Comment: i don't know why but in my project case, it worked with adding vertical-align: -15%.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `vertical-align: middle` in .material-icons { ... }

Comment: I tried but it's not working on different box padding, line-height cases

Answer (score 0):

Here an example with different line-height and paddings.

I add the class `vertical-align: middle;` in .material-icons.

The code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rafalito1989/yutqc2xL/

hope you helpful